# What is this equation used to come up with a starting value for the scale parameter of a Weibull distribution?

Tags: statistics

$\frac{-1}{\ln{(1-\frac{1}{\mu + 1})}}$

Where $\mu$ is the mean value of a random variable.

The author of this equation is using it to calculate an initial value for the scale variable in a [Weibull distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution)

I'm wondering what this equation is and why you would use it.

The equation is presented in cell 5 of [this notebook](https://github.com/ragulpr/wtte-rnn/blob/master/examples/keras/simple_example.ipynb).